# Resharper Cache size uses huge amount of disk space

Tags: resharper, resharper-9.0

I noticed that my development machine running windows server suddenly ran out of space. I ran WINDIRSTAT and see that Resharper cache is using a LOT of space..

It's a normal web project including 3 class projects as well.. The other projects on the server uses about 10 MB and this project 11 GB.... What can cause this?

[image]

Comment: I left VS open overnight and found in the morning that R# had eaten *all* the remaining disk space: 190GB.

Comment: @Anders same thing happened to me, ate 225GB.

Comment: Same thing happend to me, 219GB

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't really know what's gone wrong here - 11GB is rather excessive! I'd suggest resetting the cache (just close the solution and delete the redacted folder, or click the "Clear caches" button in the ReSharper → Options → General options page), and reloading the solution. The cache should be considerably smaller. It would probably be worth updating to the latest version of ReSharper (9.1.1 is the latest released, 9.2 is in EAP builds). If the cache is still this big, contact support, either by emailing support at jetbrains dot com, or by raising an issue directly at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

**EDIT (23/02/2018):** Removed the section on integration with Windows disk cleanup. Sadly, this isn't a completed or released feature.

Comment: I had this problem with resharper 9.2 - 150GB disk space used

Comment: Wow, that's pretty impressive. Please report that to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com (and try with 10.0.2, if you can!)

Comment: Clear cache did not work for me but deleting the folders inside /Transient seems safe. After I did it, loading a project in VS seemed faster.

Comment: Just happened to me. ReSharper 10.0.2, filled a 500GB hard drive with 360GB of caches. There were 212,034 `.sst` files in the `{solution folder}\_ReSharper.Caches\ReSharperPlatformVs144.SMT\Db` folder.

Comment: Again, if you ever see this, it's a bug. The very best thing to do is to [report it as a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=), with as much details as you can. StackOverflow is great for help, but not as a bug tracking system.

Comment: @GregSmalter - make sure you clear the cache with the solution open that is causing issues.

Comment: Happened with latest and greatest Resharper 2016.3. Sigh.

Comment: Then please report it as a bug. The dev team can't find and fix this based on a single line comment on StackOverflow. Please tell them - [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=).

Comment: One of the reasons the Transient folder is so big is that Resharper doesn't delete the splution caches of previous versions when upgrading to a new version of R#. I had 16 GB of stuff (some solution caches were 2 years old) before I manually deleted it. Resharper 2017.1

Comment: there is no "Install Windows Disk Cleanup Entry" in my resharper :/

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. It's an unfinished and untested feature that's only available in internal mode. I've removed the details from the answer.

Comment: This bug is still present in Resharper 2016.2 on Visual Studion 2015. I got a solution (~20 projects) that results in a cache of 120 GB.

Comment: This bug is still present in ReSharper 2020.2. on Visual Studio 2019. I had the cache balloon to ~300GB on a solution of 3 projects.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, JetBrains recommends you can either clear cache or you could move the cache to a separate drive or folder (especially if SSD space is a premium).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Configuring_Caches_Location.html